# Change excel filename from excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to change excel filename from a specific excel file?

For example, create a cell that will store filename, which will depend on some other cell. If I change original cell, it should rename some third file, and set its name to a cell's content.

I don't want to use any other language, to create a script or something similar.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  I assume you're also asking *how* to do that? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not without a script. You'd need VBA to do that.

Comment: @BruceWayne Sorry for not specifying the question. Haven't tried anything, since googling it didn't give me any better answers than VBA script.

Comment: @teylyn That's the only way I found so far.

Comment: There's your answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

A formula in a cell cannot change the name of a file, regardless of whether it's the current file or a different file. To achieve what you describe you will definitely need "a script or something similar".

Don't shoot the messenger. This answers your question as stated.